# Splitting a text file

Tags: java

I have this text file of the format:

```
Token:A1
sometext
Token:A2
sometext
Token:A3
```

I want to split this file into multiple files, such that
File 1 contains

```
A1
sometext
```

File 2 contains

```
A2
sometext
```

I do not have much idea about any programming or scripting language as such, what would be the best way to go about the process? I was thinking of using Java to solve the problem.

Comment: [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)( "Token:" ) ? Gives you a String[] with "A1 sometext ","A2 sometext" ...

Comment: Is "sometext" guaranteed to not contain "Token:" ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use java, I would look into using `Scanner` in conjunction with `File` and `PrintWriter` with a for loop and some exception handling you will be good to go.

import the proper libraries!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

declare the class of course

```
public class someClass{

    public static void main(String [] args){
```

now here's where stuff starts to get interesting. We use the class File to create a new file that has the name of the file to be read passed as a parameter. You can put whatever you want there whether its a path to the file or just the file name if its in the same directory as your code.

```
        File currentFile = new File("new.txt");
        if (currentFile.exists() && currentFile.canRead()){
            try{
```

next we create a scanner to *scan* through that newly created File object. the for loop continues on as long as the file has new tokens to scan through. `.hasNext()` returns true only if the input in the scanner has another token. PrintWriter writes and creates the files. I have it set that it will create the files based on the iteration of the loop (0,1,2,3 etc) but that can be easily changed. (see `new PrintWriter(i + ".txt". UTF-8);` )

```
            Scanner textContents = new Scanner(currentFile);
                for(int i = 0; textContents.hasNext(); i++){
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(i + ".txt", "UTF-8");
                    writer.println(textContents.next());
                    writer.close();
                }
```

these catch statements are super important! Your code wont even compile without them. If there is an error they will make sure your code doesn't crash. I left the inside of them empty so you can do what you see fit.

```
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // do something
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException i){
                //do something
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

and thats pretty much it! if you have any questions be sure to comment!

Answer (score 0):

There is no best way and it depends on your environment and need actually. But for any language figure out your basic algorithm and try using the best available data structure(s). If you are using Java, consider using [guava splitter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) and do look into its implementation.